LXQt shuts down instead of suspend
I've installed Debian Bookworm with LXQt on my old ASUS X205TA notebook. Almost everything works fine except when I press the Fn+Zz button (X86Sleep) bound to "/powermanager/keysuspend", the computer shuts down instead of suspend.
I've disabled all the LXQt's power management related global shortcusts and found that the key combo does nothing, so it was handled by the LXQt. I can also see there are inhibitors for those keys in systemd-inhibit.
Then I tried to manually send a DBus message like the following, which as I think is also sent on a key shortcut when it's bound to "/powermanager/keysuspend":
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.lxqt.lxqt-powermanagement /global_key_shortcuts/powermanager/keysuspend org.lxqt.global_key_shortcuts.client.activated

The computer immediately shuts down leaving the following records in the journal:
May 26 17:35:13 eee polkitd[641]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:3 (system bus name :1.37, object path /org/lxqt/PolicyKit1/Aut>
May 26 17:35:14 eee sudo[4303]: pam_unix(sudo-i:session): session closed for user root
May 26 17:35:14 eee systemd-logind[650]: The system will power off now!
May 26 17:35:14 eee systemd-logind[650]: System is powering down.
May 26 17:35:15 eee systemd[1]: Stopping session-3.scope - Session 3 of User zc2...

About the system:
liblxqt   1.2.0
Qt        5.15.6

$ uname -a
Linux eee 6.1.0-21-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.90-1 (2024-05-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Lid closing, clicking on the Suspend from the LXQt main menu, or just an LXQt's idling time out make the computer suspend as it should (as well as root required commands, like pm-suspend, systemctl suspend).
Upd. I found a workaround by just binding X86Sleep to the command "lxqt-leave --suspend", but still wonder why the observed behavior happened. Is it a bug worthy to report or just some misconfiguration.

Probably because it isn't recognized as a suspend key? You may try changing how power key (or hibernate key) is handled in /etc/systemd/logind.conf (make sure you restart logind, or reboot, afterwards).

Isn't the fact that the command "systemd-inhibit --list --mode=block" shows inhibitors for all  handle-*-key events, allows to rule out the logind from this issue?
